# Only half of jQuery animation is running

Tags: jquery

Only the changes in width in this jQuery animation is running, why isn't the color change animation also happening?

```
$('#code').animate({ 
  'background':'#dddddd', 
  'background':'rgb(221, 221, 221)', 
  'width':'16px', 
  'width':'1rem' 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to animate the background color which you can't do with jQuery alone. To achieve what you're trying to do above in your description you need to include the [color animation plugin which is available here.](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)

Or you can also use [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) which provides the same functions.

After you have included that you're code should work as expected.

Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SfWAS/) with the color plugin included.

```
$('#color').on('click',function(){
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#400101', color:'#fff'}); 
});
```

Comment: Ah, okay. I thought one could do it with stand alone jQuery.

Comment: Don't worry I did the first time too.